# Aave Flashloan `reverted with reason '73'`

Tags: solidity, mocha, revert-opcode, hardhat, aave

I'm getting an error when attempting to execute an Aave V2 Flashloan within a Hardhat-mocha test while connected to a fork of the Kovan network. It's unclear to me what revert reason "73" corresponds to.

Answer (score 0):

Aave has an error code mapping available on their documentation website, which basically mirrors what is in their protocol repository:

- https://docs.aave.com/developers/guides/troubleshooting-errors
- https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/master/contracts/protocol/libraries/helpers/Errors.sol